# Is there a way to show y-axis labels more prominent in Plotly

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I wanted to show the '0' (Zero) more prominent on the y-axis for the figure generated by Plotly. When the dataset is low, the '0' (Zero) is clearly visible, when the dataset is huge, the zero is trimmed in the bottom left corner. (See highlighted yellow part in the figure attached)

[image]

Comment: A range setting on the y-axis will lift the position slightly to zero. For example, `fig.update_yaxes(range=[100,max()])`. See the [reference](https://plotly.com/python/axes/) on axes for the rest.

Comment: I recommend using log scale if you have very large values.

Comment: It's not possible to say for sure without looking at your code. I would _guess_ that you've set specific ranges for your axes. If that's the case, lower the minimum of your x-axis range, so there is no label where y = 0. For example, if the first label is 5B for the x-axis, and the range is something like 5B to 5T, then set the range to 4B to 5T.